# How do I properly jail a user in Debian, giving them access to select applications?

Tags: debian-lenny, chroot

After [failing to use makejail](https://serverfault.com/questions/187927/how-do-i-jail-a-user-in-debian-lenny-using-makejail), I followed [a howto for setting up a jail](http://www.howtoforge.com/chroot_ssh_sftp_debian_etch_p2) using a script (this one is for Debian etch, but I'm using lenny -- seems to work ok though). However, it gives the user a very limited environment with almost no applications available (e.g. no vim, emacs, cat, tail, etc).

To solve cat and tail I just copied the binaries from `/bin` to `/home/jail/bin` (which feels a little wrong). And for the other apps, I just used `mount --bind /usr /home/jail/usr` so that the user has access to most stuff (I also had to mount `/lib` and `/etc/alternatives`).

Now `emacs` and `vim` seem to work ok, but I'm not entirely convinced this was the best approach -- is there a more elegant and maintainable approach, or is jailing users generally a huge chore?

Answer (score 1):

Jailing users is generally a huge chore.

I'm not 100% sure on your implementation but its' almost certain that your bind mount to /usr and /lib specifically BREAK the jail. That's like providing an inmate with their own personal tunnel to the outside world ... it's just exactly what a chroot was supposed to avoid.

Instead you'll need to setup your jail creation script to COPY everything the jailed users will need into their own private environment as you started to do with `cat` and `tail`.

Comment: Hmm, as I suspected. And what about all the supporting libs? I was hoping maybe there's a script that would somehow copy the Debian package contents to the jail. A command like this would be handy: `apt-get-jail install emacs /home/jail`

Comment: There are a few tools to create jails. See: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jail